# Resource library getting ignored in h:graphicImage

Tags: image, jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I have the following tag:

```
<h:graphicImage value="Circle_Yellow.png" library="images" />
```

In my folder I have the following structure:

```
/resources/images/.....
/WEB-INF/....
/*.xhtml
```

When rendered that image shows up as:

```
<img src="Circle_Yellow.png">
```

However I do see other things using resources, for example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/www/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtmlln=primefaces"></script>
```

And if I go to `/www/javax.faces.resource/Circle_Yellow.png?ln=images` it works.

So what could I possibly be doing wrong that my library gets ignored on the h:graphicImage. Also it isn't just as an image, I have a css file that is failing too.

I'm using mojarra 2.1.16 and primefaces 3.4.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `value` attribute takes an URL, not the resource name. To specify the resource name, use the `name` attribute.

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="Circle_Yellow.png" />
```

See also [the `<h:graphicImage>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/graphicImage.html) for details.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your usage of the `library` attribute is not entirely right. Please carefully read [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) You should be using it as

```
<h:graphicImage name="images/Circle_Yellow.png" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed the name/value thing. I'm trying to use libraries mainly as a way to not have to worry about paths for now as I am just starting this project and I'm not settled on how it is even going to get deployed.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, JSF2 resource libraries are the way to go. The `<h:graphicImage value>` is actually a leftover from JSF 1.x.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this,

```
<h:graphicImage value="resources/images/Circle_Yellow.png"/>
```

or

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="Circle_Yellow.png" />
```

and include your css like below

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
```

Comment: The last two are not good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used